# Remove specific columns in dataframe with same id on date condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two datasets:

1. One contains house energy certificates issued the last 10 years with an ID for the house and the date it was issued. One house could have more certificates issued, as they can renew it.
2. The other contains all transactions of houses for the last 10 years
   and the ID (Which is the same id as in the first dataset)

I have merged them using

```
mergeALL= pd.merge(mergeTranDwelling,EnergySimple, left_on=['matrikkel2019', "bygningsnr"], right_on=['matrikkel2019', 'Bygningsnummer'], how='inner')
```

I then get something like this(Snippet of dataframe):

```
transaction_id  address_id  official_date   certificate     issued_date
83866285    1157600091      2016-05-25      A2012-278940    17.12.2012 17:44:17
83866285    1157600091      2016-05-25      A2012-278941    17.12.2012 17:48:35
83866285    1157600091      2016-05-25      A2016-638538    22.02.2016 10:16:12
83866285    1157600091      2016-05-25      A2016-638577    22.02.2016 10:22:45
83866285    1157600091      2016-05-25      A2019-1065662   21.10.2019 15:39:30
```

Because each house can have several energy certificates values, each transaction can get several certificates attached to it. I want each **transaction_id** to have the certificate with the **issued_date** that is closest but before the **official_date**. In the case above I want to remove all the certificates on this **tranasction_id** except :

```
83866285    1157600091      2016-05-25      A2016-638577    22.02.2016 10:22:45
```

I have tried using this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60434720/12939497
but I have to merge the datasets on two columns (matrikkel2019 , bygningsr), therefore I cannot use merge.asof.

I am also open for doing the merge in another way ( this is another question about the same problem:[Merging two DataFrames (Datasets) on a specific ID column but with Date condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60433566/12939497))

Comment: check the answer below and let me know if not what you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended your df wiht one more address transaction_id for better testing..and taken dataframe from excel you can modify that part as per your need..

```
input_df

transaction_id  address_id  official_date   certificate issued_date
83866285    1157600091  5/25/2016   A2012-278940    17.12.2012 17:44:17
83866285    1157600091  5/25/2016   A2012-278941    17.12.2012 17:48:35
83866285    1157600091  5/25/2016   A2016-638538    22.02.2016 10:16:12
83866285    1157600091  5/25/2016   A2016-638577    22.02.2016 10:22:45
83866285    1157600091  5/25/2016   A2019-1065662   21.10.2019 15:39:30
83866286    1157600093  5/25/2019   A2012-278940    17.12.2012 17:44:17
83866286    1157600093  5/25/2019   A2012-278941    17.12.2012 17:48:35
83866286    1157600093  5/25/2019   A2016-638538    22.02.2016 10:16:12
83866286    1157600093  5/25/2019   A2016-638577    22.02.2016 10:22:45
83866286    1157600093  5/25/2019   A2019-1065662   21.11.2019 15:39:30
```

..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import re

input_df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')

# convert columns in date time 

input_df['issued_date'] = pd.to_datetime(input_df['issued_date'])
input_df['official_date'] = pd.to_datetime(input_df['official_date'])

# Add below column just for calculation
input_df['diff_days']= (input_df['issued_date']-input_df['official_date']).abs()
print(input_df)

# Filter the group of transaction_id
input_df=input_df.loc[input_df.groupby('transaction_id').diff_days.idxmin()]

# Now remove temp column
input_df = input_df.drop(['diff_days'], axis=1)
print(input_df)
```

Output -

```
   3        83866285  1157600091    2016-05-25   A2016-638577 2016-02-22 10:22:45
   9        83866286  1157600093    2019-05-25  A2019-1065662 2019-11-21 15:39:30
```

Comment: Nearly the solution I am looking for but I want only the first row (nr 3) I  want one certificate per transaction id, which has the closest **issue_date** before **official_date** and discard all the other on that ID. Want to do that for all unique transactions ID's in my  dataset

Comment: For your data it will give only 1 row,  I have added data for 1 more certificate so it is showing 2 rows as there are 2 different certificate in my data....

Comment: Yes, okay! I just had to remove the abs() and then fetch all the negative days, then using the abs() after to find the closest **issue_date** but before **official_date**! Thank you so much, you helped me a lot