# Getting Incorrect answers with combination of groupby and min() and also with combination of Loc, groupby and min in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have a Dataframe like this :**

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr7pw.png)

- [Actual Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNNOC.png)

I am trying to create a Dataframe which gives me the minimum value for each Category

I tried

```
new_df = df.groupby('Category')[Reduction].min()
```

This gives me wrong answer. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuCXx.png) is the Output that I am getting
Expected Outcome is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTaln.png)

and also tried

```
new_df = df.loc[df.groupby('Category')[Reduction].idxmin() , :]
```

This one gives me a `ValueError.`

Can anyone help as to what I might be doing wrong? I tried searching for all possible answers and the only one I found is that there may be blank value but there is none.

Comment: could you copy and paste tyour dataframe and your expected output?

Comment: df.groupby(['Category'])['Reduction'].min()

Comment: @JoelBondurant : Doesnt help as it gives the same output.

Comment: What is your expected output? Please follow [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have Added the images with mimimum needed Dataframe and expected output and actual output. Please help.

Comment: hi please share the daat frame in your question with sample records like below answer than it would be easy to understand the question...           ....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60693605/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the 'Reduction' column values as strings (including % sign). If you use `.min()` on this, then the values will be treated as strings and minimum will be calculated on strings. Instead if you convert the 'Reduction' column values to `float`, and apply `.min()` you should be able to achieve what you need.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['14-06-1995', '15-06-1995', '16-06-1995', '17-06-1995', '18-06-1995', '19-06-1995', '20-06-1995'],
                   'Category': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2',  'A2', 'A3', 'A3'],
                   'Reduction': ['-1.91%', '-1.32%', '-12.34%', '-2.12%', '-1.78%', '-1.24%', '-1.20%']})
# strip off the '%' sign and convert to float
df['Reduction'] = df['Reduction'].str.rstrip('%').astype('float')
# group by and assign the min value to column 'min'
new_df = df.groupby('Category')['Reduction'].agg(min=min).reset_index()
# convert the 'min' column value back to string and append '%' sign 
new_df['min'] = new_df['min'].astype(str)+'%'
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  Category      min
0       A1  -12.34%
1       A2   -2.12%
2       A3   -1.24%
```

If you want to do this conversion when reading your data frame, you can do this by adding `converters` to your `pd.read_csv()` parameters.

```
def convert_percentage(percentage):
    return float(percentage.rstrip('%'))

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', converters={'Reduction': convert_percentage})
```

Is this what you are expecting? Or is your problem different that what I stated above?

Answer (score 0):

Your `'Drawdown'` column is an `dtype:object`, only numerical values will have `min()`
First convert your `'Drawdown'` to `float` type

```
df['Drawdown'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Drawdown'].str.strip('%'), errors='coerce')
df.groupby('ATH No.')['Drawdown'].min()
```